# How to prevent TextChanged event when I select an item in combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a [`TextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) event on my [`ComboBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.aspx) like;

```
private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     foreach (var item in comboBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToList())
     {
         comboBox1.Items.Remove(item);
     }

     foreach (string item in InputBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Cast<string>().Where(s => s.Contains(comboBox1.Text)).ToList())
     {
         comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
     }
}
```

As an explanation, when I change the text of combobox, I want to get `string` values contains in [`AutoCompleteCustomSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcombobox.autocompletecustomsource.aspx) on `InputBox` (which is [`TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx)).

It works fine when I search them but when I select the item, obviously `TextChanged` event triggered again and [`Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text.aspx) property of [`Combobox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx) will reset.

How to solve this?

Comment: A cheap win would be to set a boolean in the selectionchanged event... I presume the sender in both cases is the same thing?

Comment: @Sayse You are saying `SelectedValueCahnged` event? When I select a result, both `comboBox1_TextChanged` and `comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged` events `sender`s `Text` properties are empty string.

Comment: Yes I was thinking for the boolean idea you would need this set in the [SelectedValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event (to false) to state that you wish to bypass the event. My second thought was that the sender may be null when typing and the combobox when coming from the changed selection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood correctly then i think you want to hide the TextChange event of the combobox. If it is then you can create a custom control inherited by ComboBox and override the TextChange event.

```
public partial class MyCombo : ComboBox
{
    public MyCombo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    bool bFalse = false;
    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        //Here you can handle the TextChange event if want to suppress it 
        //just place the base.OnTextChanged(e); line inside the condition
        if (!bFalse)
            base.OnTextChanged(e);
    }
    protected override void OnSelectionChangeCommitted(EventArgs e)
    {
        bFalse = true;
        base.OnSelectionChangeCommitted(e);
    }
    protected override void OnTextUpdate(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextUpdate(e);
        bFalse = false; //this event will be fire when user types anything. but, not when user selects item from the list.
    }
}
```

**EDITED:**
Another simple soution is use `TextUpdate` event instead of `TextChange` and keep your combobox as it is without creating another custom control.

```
private void myCombo1_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in myCombo1.Items.Cast<string>().ToList())
    {
        myCombo1.Items.Remove(item);
    }

    foreach (string item in myCombo1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Cast<string>().Where(s => s.Contains(myCombo1.Text)).ToList())
    {
        myCombo1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

`TextUpdate` event will call only when user types anything in combobox. But, not when user selects item from the drop down list. So, this will not resent the added items.

You can also change the where condition if you wish to return all matched items in both cases(Upper and Lower). Suppose you have a two items in the list `1. Microsoft Sql Server, 2. microsoft office` then what would be the result if i type `microsoft` only.

```
Where(s => s.ToLower().Contains(comboBox1.Text.ToLower()))
```

**[Sample Code](http://www.dantainfosoft.a78.org/DragForm.rar)**

[image]

Comment: But you can't call `OnSelectionChangeCommitted ` inside `OnSelectionChangeCommitted` with `base`.

Comment: i haven't called it.. its a method overriding it will be generated automatically once you select the method from the intellisense.

Comment: Why do you need another `MyCombo` class? Because when you use `InitializeComponent` in it, it brokes the designer code of the window form.

Comment: You cannot handle the TextChange event outside the user control and the value in the combobox is reseting initially. So, you have to prevent the combox to call the OnTextChange initally.

Comment: You can download and check the sample project from [here](http://www.dantainfosoft.a78.org/DragForm.rar)

Comment: +1 (and deleted my answer) - The text update is exactly what Soner appears to need. (Tested myself)

Comment: @Shell Sorry for the late response. You are right looks like `TextUpdate` event is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @Sayse I tested either. This event is exactly what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sayse already said:

Add a boolean:

```
private bool codeCalled = new bool();
```

In your textChanged:

```
if(codeCalled == true)
{
    codeCalled = false;   
    return;
}
else
{
     codeCalled = true;
    //your foreachcode here        
}
```

That should do the trick.

Tested and is working.

Also tested and working, also not elegant:

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox.TextChanged -= textBox_TextChanged;

    //yourcode

    textBox.TextChanged += textBox_TextChanged;
}
```

Comment: But this won't work because every time `TextChanged` triggered, your `codeCalled` will be `false` by default. That's why every time of that, this `else` part will work and items will cleared again.

Comment: yeah ... well the updated answer is tested and will work. +1 Dmitry, don't know where my thoughts were when I wrote this.