# Prevent text from changing when SelectedIndex changes on ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox, wpf-controls

I'm creating a `UserControl` from a `ComboBox`. My goal is for the user to be able to write a part of the name of a card, and as he writes it, the cards that match the string are shown below, and then the user can use the cursors to select the card he wants.

This is what I have up to now:

**XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="UrSimulator.View.UserControls.SearchMaxedCardComboBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MaxedCardTemplate">
            <!-- The template works so I've removed it to avoid clutter -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
        <ComboBox x:Name="SearchBox"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 
                  IsEditable="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" IsTextSearchEnabled="False" 
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MaxedCardTemplate}"
                  TextBoxBase.TextChanged="ComboBox_TextChanged" 
                  GotFocus="ComboBox_GotFocus" 
                  LostFocus="ComboBox_LostFocus"/>
</UserControl>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class SearchMaxedCardComboBox : UserControl
{
    public InMemoryManager InMemoryManager { get; set; } // In Memory Database where cards are stored
    public CardBase SelectedCard { get; set; }

    private string DefaultText; 

    public SearchMaxedCardComboBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DefaultText = Properties.UIStrings.ui_calculator_search_card; // == Name (min 2 chars)
        SearchBox.Text = DefaultText;
    }

    private void ComboBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox control = sender as ComboBox;
        control.Text = "";
        control.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    }
    private void ComboBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox control = sender as ComboBox;
        control.IsDropDownOpen = false;

        if (SelectedCard == null)
            control.Text = DefaultText;
        else
            control.Text = SelectedCard.Name;
    }
    private void ComboBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox control = sender as ComboBox;

        if (control.Text == DefaultText)
            return;

        Debug.Assert(InMemoryManager != null);            

        List<string> names;
        if (control.Text.Length < 2) // If a search happens with 1 char or an empty string it slows down too much
            names = new List<string>();
        else
            names = InMemoryManager.LookForCardNames(control.Text); // List<string> with the names

        List<CardBase> cards = new List<CardBase>();
        foreach (string name in names)
            cards.Add(InMemoryManager.GetCardBase(name));

        control.Items.Clear();
        foreach (CardBase card in cards)
            control.Items.Add(new MaxedCardBaseViewModel(card));
    }

    private void SearchBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox control = sender as ComboBox;
        if (control.SelectedItem != null)
            SelectedCard = ((MaxedCardBaseViewModel)control.SelectedItem).Card;
    }
}
```

**Problem:** When the `SelectedIndex` changes, the text on the `ComboBox` changes too. The text then matches the selected item (in this case it becomes the class name of the item), `TextChanged` Fires up again, the search is done with no result, and the list of items ends empty.

How can avoid the text being changed when selecting an item?

---

**Update:** I'm trying what this [commenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797653/prevent-text-from-changing-when-selectedindex-changes-on-combobox#comment44006095_27797653) said, and it made me realize that my question somewhat suffers from the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), still I'm working around a similar code from the question, and will try with the "Auto-Complete Combobox" code that he links.

I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662792/how-to-prevent-textchanged-event-when-i-select-an-item-in-combobox) that is in essence the same as mine, but for `WinForms`, and `WPF` doesn't have a `OnSelectionChangeCommitted` nor `TextUpdate` alternative as they work differently from `OnSelectionChange` and `TextChanged`.

Comment: It looks like your [`X problem`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) can be solved by using normal auto-complete combobox (see, to example, [this](http://arkeshkorat.blogspot.de/2013/05/auto-complete-combobox-in-wpf.html)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using what [Sinatr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1997232/sinatr) linked I've managed to make a control that works as I desire. It does the following things:

- The base is a `ComboBox`, so it has a `TextBox` and a `ListBox` integrated on a single control.
- The `ItemsSource` is updated when the `Text` changes, so it only shows the elements that
- When the user changes the selection via keyboard it has to confirm it with Enter or Tab
- Only "confirmed" selections (Enter, Tab, Mouse) will modify the SelectedCard
- It only searches when the Text is minimum 2 chars (by default)

It still has a few quirks:

- If the user changes the index with the keyboard (Up/Down) and then clicks outside, then the last highlighted item gets selected. Is not a big problem but an annoyance so it doesn't get to be a priority.
- A visual bug when the using an `ItemsTemplate` and the list is big enough to not fit, when scrolling with the keyboard past the limit of the view, the selected item is not scrolled to.

Even with those minimal quirks, I consider it resolved.

Here is the code:

**XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.SearchCardControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UrSimulator.View.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CardTemplate">
        <!-- ... -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <local:SearchComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" 
            x:Name="SearchBox"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CardTemplate}"
            IsEditable="True" 
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" 
            IsTextSearchEnabled="False" 
            StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
            TextBoxBase.TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" 
            SelectionChanged="SearchBox_SelectionChanged" 
            LostKeyboardFocus="SearchBox_LostKeyboardFocus" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class SearchCardControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedCardProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedCard", typeof(CardBase), typeof(SearchCardControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    public InMemoryManager InMemoryManager { get; set; }
    public CardBase SelectedCard
    {
        get { return (CardBase)GetValue(SelectedCardProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SelectedCardProperty, value);
            this.Notify(PropertyChanged);
        }
    }

    private int _minimumSearchChars;
    public int MinimumSearchChars
    {
        get { return _minimumSearchChars; }
        set { if (value > 0) _minimumSearchChars = value; }
    }
    public string DefaultText { get { return String.Format(Properties.UIStrings.ui_calculator_search_card, MinimumSearchChars); } }

    public SearchCardControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SearchBox.SetTextWithoutSearching(DefaultText);
        MinimumSearchChars = 2;
    }

    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SearchComboBox control = (SearchComboBox)sender;
        if (control.IsSearchNeeded)
        {
            if (control.Text.Length >= MinimumSearchChars)
                control.ItemsSource = Search(control.Text);
            else
                control.ItemsSource = new List<object>();
        }
    }
    private void SearchBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SearchComboBox control = (SearchComboBox)sender;
        if (control.SelectedItem == null)
            control.SetTextWithoutSearching(DefaultText);
        else
        {
            SelectedCard = (CardBase)control.SelectedItem;
            control.SetTextWithoutSearching(SelectedCard.Name);
        }
    }
    private void SearchBox_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectedCard == null)
            SearchBox.SetTextWithoutSearching(DefaultText);
        else
            SearchBox.Text = SelectedCard.Name;
    }

    private List<CardBase> Search(string partialName)
    {
        // Whatever floats your boat
        // MyList.FindAll(x => x.FieldToCompareForExampleCardName.IndexOf(partialName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
        // Or you could implement a delegate here
    }
}

internal class SearchComboBox : ComboBox
{
    internal bool IsSearchNeeded = true;
    internal SelectionChangedEventArgs LastOnSelectionChangedArgs;

    internal void SetTextWithoutSearching(string text)
    {
        IsSearchNeeded = false;
        Text = text;
        IsSearchNeeded = true;
    }

    protected override void OnGotKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsSearchNeeded)
        {
            Text = "";
            IsDropDownOpen = true;
        }
        base.OnGotKeyboardFocus(e);
    }
    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {  
        if (SelectedIndex != -1)
            LastOnSelectionChangedArgs = e;
    }
    protected override void OnDropDownClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (LastOnSelectionChangedArgs != null)
            base.OnSelectionChanged(LastOnSelectionChangedArgs);
        base.OnDropDownClosed(e);
    }
    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab || e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            IsDropDownOpen = false;
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
        {
            SelectedIndex = -1;
            IsDropDownOpen = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Down)
                this.IsDropDownOpen = true;
            base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
        }
    }
    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(e.Key == Key.Up || e.Key == Key.Down || e.Key == Key.Tab || e.Key == Key.Enter))
            base.OnKeyUp(e);
    }
}
```